# Trigger Jenkins pipeline from Argo

Tags: jenkins, argocd, argo-workflows, argo

I am building a data pipeline, orchestrated by Argo. It has several steps, one of which is already implemented as a Jenkins pipeline.

Although I don't like the idea, the requirement would be to trigger the Jenkins pipeline from Argo and save its output (which is then used in other step).

I don't find on the internet anything about the following questions:

*How one can trigger a Jenkins pipeline from Argo?*

Could you please clarify that for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it Argo CD or Workflows?